# Using Logical AND Operators && in foreach php

Tags: php, foreach, logical-operators

I have the following code for an image gallery :

```
$directory = 'some path';
$thumbs_directory = 'some path';
foreach (glob($directory.'/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $file) 
foreach (glob($thumbs_directory.'/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $file2)
{

    if($file=='.' || $file == '..') continue;
    $file_parts = explode('.',$file);
    $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));
    $title = basename($file);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);
    $title = str_replace("_"," ",$title);
    $nomargin='';
    if(($i+1)%4==0) $nomargin='nomargin';
    echo '
    <div class="pic '.$nomargin.'" style="background:url('.$file2.') no-repeat 50% 50%;">
    <a href="'.$file.'" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>
    </div>';
    $i++;
}
```

I need to combine these foreach statements through the Logical AND operator && so that both conditions are satisfied at the same time. Is it possible ? I've tried numerous times, but always ends up in a Syntax error.

Please note that I need $file and $file2 variables defined perfectly. That is only the way for the thumbnails to associate with the images properly.

Comment: You are looking for `array_merge()`

Comment: I think what's thrown people off here is your repeated mention of "logical AND", rather than the actual relationship you're trying to maintain between the two lists of files.

Comment: I'm not a core programmer. So I am not able to use programming terminologies.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not simply refactor the meaty logic into a common function, and then call it twice?

For example:

```
function doSomething($directory) {
    foreach (glob($directory.'/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {
        /* Whatever */
    }
}

...

doSomething($directory);
doSomething($thumbs_directory);
```

Answer (score 1):

To map images to their respective thumbnail images, I would rather choose a different approach:

```
$directory = 'some path';
$thumbs_directory = 'some path';

// Get all images
$images = glob($directory.'/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

// Iterate over all images
foreach ($images as $image) {
    // Construct path to thumbnail
    $thumbnail = $thumbs_directory .'/'. basename($image);

    // Check if thumbnail exists
    if (!file_exists($thumbnail)) {
        continue; // skip this image
    }

    // .. continue as before

    echo '
        <div class="pic '.$nomargin.'" style="background:url('.$thumbnail.') no-repeat 50% 50%;">
        <a href="'.$image.'" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>
        </div>
    ';
}
```

}

Comment: But I need $file and $file2 to be defined perfectly. Please see the code in my question to get a clear view

Comment: @rnvipin Didn't understand your question correctly, have edited my answer!

Comment: You are the one who did it finally :) Thanks a ton ! I don't have enough reputation to vote for your answer atm, but I'll make sure to do so once I'm eligible. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, if you want to loop over the image files that exist in both directories, you should look into using php's [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

```
$directory = 'some path';
$thumbs_directory = 'some path';

$files_in_dir1 = glob($directory.'/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$files_in_dir2 = glob($thumbs_directory.'/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$files_in_both_dirs = array_intersect($files_in_dir1, $files_in_dir2);

foreach ($files_in_both_dirs as $filename) {
  // Code
}
```

Comment: I think you got the actual question right. OP is looking for mapping images onto thumbnails. It may however require to map basenames from both directories onto each other first, and then array_intersect_assoc or something.